# ARC Memory Leak in cellForRowAtIndexPath when accessing [EKEvent notes]

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nsstring, ekevent

I'm using ARC with xCode 4.6 and I'm getting a memory leak when trying to access the `.notes` property of an `EKEvent` to assign to a string in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

The funny thing is, the leak never appears until I toggle a "paid/unpaid" button in any cell, which does not call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, although both methods need access to the singleton which holds my arrays of `EKEvents`.

According to Instruments, the leak is happening because of this line:

```
eventNotes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [currentEvent notes]];
```

[image]

`eventNotes` is an `ivar` I declared in my .h file.

I've tried the following using both an `ivar` and creating a new instance variable on the fly, and nothing seems to work:

```
NSString *eventNotes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [currentEvent notes]];
eventNotes = [currentEvent notes];
eventNotes = currentEvent.notes;
NSString *eventNotes = [currentEvent notes];
NSString *eventNotes = currentEvent.notes;
NSString *eventNotes = [NSString stringWithString:[currentEvent notes]];
NSString *eventNotes = [NSString stringWithString:currentEvent.notes];
eventNotes = [NSString stringWithString:currentEvent.notes];
```

The list goes on, here is my cellForRowAtIndexPathCode, where the leak is happening.
I'm completely new to memory management so please! be descriptive.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     //Custom Cell...
     UTATableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
     cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableviewCell.png"]];
     cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

     //reset cell view attributes
     cell.paidButton.tag = 1;
     [cell.paidButton setAlpha:1.0f];
     [cell.paidButton setSelected:NO];
     [cell.paidButton setEnabled:YES];

     cell.title.tag = 2;
     cell.title.text = NULL;

     cell.subtitle.tag = 3;
     cell.subtitle.text = NULL;

     [cell.paidButton addTarget:self action:@selector(togglePaid:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

     if ([_yearSwitcher selectedSegmentIndex] == 0) {

          //lastYearsUTAEvents is an MSMutable array and a property of sharedEventData, which is a singleton class...             
          NSMutableArray *currentArray = [sharedEventData.lastYearsUTAEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
          EKEvent *currentEvent = [currentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
          NSDate *date = [currentEvent startDate];
          NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
          [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
          [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
          NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
          cell.title.text = dateString;

-leak---> eventNotes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [currentEvent notes]];

          if ([eventNotes rangeOfString:@" - Paid"].location != NSNotFound) {
               cell.subtitle.text = [eventNotes stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" - Paid" withString:@""];
               [cell.paidButton setSelected:YES];

          } else {        
               cell.subtitle.text = eventNotes;
               [cell.paidButton setSelected:NO];
          }

      } else {

          // same as above but different array....
      }
  return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution was to cast (EKEvent *) when accessing an EKEvent object from an array of EKEvents**.

I fetched events from the calendar and stored them in an `NSMutableArray`called `lastYearsUTAEvents` (which is a property of a singleton class).

When accessing an event in the array, I had to use a cast it in order to prevent the memory leak for some reason. So instead of:

```
 NSMutableArray *currentArray = [sharedEventData.lastYearsUTAEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
 EKEvent *currentEvent = [currentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I cast the object as an **(EKEvent *)** while grabbing it out of the array, and nothing is leaking now. (I also optimized the previous 2 lines of code into 1):

```
EKEvent *currentEvent = (EKEvent *)[[sharedEventData.thisYearsUTAEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

At first, I was confused about even being able to change the `.notes` property at all because in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKCalendarItemClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010882-CH1-SW12), it's an `NSString`, not an `NSMutableString`, so I'm assuming when you save an EKEvent (or, in my case, edit one) it saves over the existing one since there is no replace method for saving an event. Only Save and Remove.

On top of all the confusion, `.notes` isn't even a property of an `EKEvent`. It's a property of [`EKCalendarItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKCalendarItemClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010882-CH1-SW12).

Hope this helps someone in the future...